# Binance API Python - How to use a specific output

Tags: python, binance

When i let my bot place an order, it gives me something like the following output:

```
[{
"symbol": "BNBBTC",
"orderId": 3301945,
"clientOrderId": "6gCrw2kRUAF9CvJDGP16IP",
"transactTime": 1507725176595,
"price": "0.00000000",
"origQty": "10.00000000",
"executedQty": "10.00000000",
"status": "FILLED",
"timeInForce": "GTC",
"type": "LIMIT",
"side": "SELL"
}]
```

I want my bot to automatically be able to fetch the orderId so that it is able to continue working with that by itself without me manually typing in the Id.

For example, if i want to cancel that order:

```
result = client.cancel_order(
symbol='BNBBTC',
orderId='orderId')
```

I'd need to ask for the Id first, replace that 'orderId' and run again to be able to cancel the order. There has to be a way to automate this, right?

Comment: so you just want to get the `orderId` from the returned dictionary?

Comment: Yeah i want to be able to automatically use the orderId, print it, use it in another function etc. That's probably basic know-how, but i am a complete beginner :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at some basic tutorials on [`dictionaries`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary). Getting values of keys is and should be the first thing you learn.

In your case with a dictionary as provided, the structure is very plain. So to get the value of `orderId` you can just use `your_dictionary.get("orderId")`.

Note I use `.get` instead of `dict[key]`, this way if there is no `orderId` in your dictionary the console will only output `None`.  Whereas if I use `dict[key]` and there is no such key, we will get a `KeyError`.

Comment: I think i know how dictionaries and lists work, but i just can't figure it out.. I actually think the output i am getting when placing an order is not a dictionary, it's a list. When i try to use your_dictionary.get("orderId"), i get the Error:   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: So, why in the example do you share a dictionary?

Comment: [{'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'orderId': 3301945, 'clientOrderId': '6gCrw2kRUAF9CvJDGP16IP', ..... }]
That's the output i get if i print my order. Sorry, guess i forgot the square brackets if that makes a difference..

Comment: please change that in your question. Also you can just do `actualDict = outputDict[0]`. Then preform my provided code `actualDict.get('yourId')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it! What should i take a look at to understand that `actualDict = outputDict[0]` . Does that just turn a list into a dictionary by removing the square brackets?

Comment: Perfect, thanks again you are my hero this week. Was stuck because of this way too long lol